# How to speed up query execution time in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I would like to speed up the execution time of my queries as much as possible. As example, we can write two queries with the identical meaning

```
select * from <TABLENAME> where start_date BETWEEN date'2019-11-01' AND date'2019-12-01'
```

and

```
select * from <TABLENAME> where start_date > date'2019-11-01' AND start_date < date'2019-12-01'
```

They will have the same output, but the second query will work faster. So, do you know similar features in Oracle's SQL?

Comment: If you mean "Is query optimization done differently in PL/SQL as opposed to Oracle RDBMS" the answer is No. All queries which are part of a PL/SQL procedure are executed by the Oracle database, so making a PL/SQL query run faster is no different than making an Oracle query run faster, as it's exactly the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `BETWEEN` operator is inclusive of both endpoints, so your operators need to be `>=` and `<=`  :)

Comment: Assuming that the point @AleksandrH has given is just a typo in your question, what gave you the impression that the second query was faster? I doubt that.

Comment: @stickybit - the second query *will* probably run faster than the first query, if the second is run immediately after the first. In this case execution of the first query would have caused much of the required data to be cached, causing the second query to complete faster. However, I suspect the two queries should have identical query plans and costs.